# Why are new programming languages shifting types to the other side?

Tags: programming-languages

If you look at Rust, Go, Swift, TypeScript and a few others, and compare them to C/C++, the first thing that I noticed was how the types have moved positions.

```
int one = 1;
```

In comparsion to:

```
let one:int = 1;
```

My question: Why?

To me, personally, it is weird reading type specifiers that far into the line, since I am very used to them being on the left. So it interests me on why the type specifiers are being moved - and this not being the case with just one, but many modern/new languages that are on the table.

Comment: look at where the types are in UML.even when c++ was dominant UML was putting types in this different order.

Comment: hmm...neither of the answers to those questions mention Curry Howard Isomorphism (where `a: A` would mean *a is a proof of proposition A* or *a is type A*). I.E. the actual reasons that type theory would give for this practice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> To me, personally, it is weird reading type specifiers that far into the line, since I am very used to them being on the left

And English is the best language because it is the only language where the words are spoken in the same order I think them. One wonders why anyone speaks French at all, with the words all in the wrong order!

> So it interests me on why the type specifiers are being moved - and this not being the case with just one, but many modern/new languages that are on the table.

I note that you ignore the existence of the many older languages which use this pattern. Visual Basic (mid 1990s) immediately comes to mind.

```
Function F(x As String) As Object
```

Pascal, 1970s:

```
var
  Set1 : set of 1..10;
```

Simply-typed lambda calculus, a programming language invented *before computers*, in the 1940s:

```
λx:S.λy:T:S-->T-->S
```

The whole ML family. I could go on. There are plenty of very old languages that use the types on the right convention.

But we can get far older than the 1940s. When you say in mathematics `f : Q --> R`, you are putting the name of the function on the left and the type -- a map from Q to R -- on the right. When you say x∈R to indicate that x is a real, you're putting the type on the right. "Type on the right" predates type on the left in C by literally **centuries**. This is not anything new!

In fact the "types on the left" syntax is the weird one! It just seems natural to you because you happen to have used a language that uses this convention in your formative years.

The types on the right syntax is much superior, for numerous reasons.  Just a few:

```
var x : int = 1;
function y(z : int) : string { ... }
```

emphasizes that x is a *variable* and y is a *function*. If the type comes to the left and you see `int y` then you don't know whether it is a function or a variable until later. This makes programs harder for humans to read, which is bad enough. As a compiler developer, let me tell you it is quite inconvenient that the type comes on the left in C#. (I could point out numerous inconsistencies in how C# syntax deals with the positions of types.)

Another reason: In the "type on the right" syntax you can make types optional.  If you have

```
var x : int = 1;
```

then you can easily say "well, we can infer the int, and so eliminate it"

```
var x = 1;
```

but if the int is on the left, then what do you do?

Inverting this: you mention TypeScript. TypeScript is a gradually-typed JavaScript. The convention in JavaScript is already

```
var x = 1;
function f(y) { }
```

Given that, plainly it is easier to modify both existing code, and the language as a whole, to introduce optional type elements on the right than it would be to make the "var" and "function" keywords replaced by a type.

Consider also the positioning. When you say:

```
int x = 1;
```

then the two things that must be consistent -- the type and the initializer -- are as far apart as they possibly can be. With `var x : int = 1;` they are side by side.  And in

```
int f() {
   ...
   ...
   return 123;
}
```

what have we got?  The return is logically *as far to the right as possible*, so why does the function declaration move the type of the return *as far to the left as possible*?"  With the type on the right syntax we have this nice flow:

```
function f(x : string) : int 
{ ... ... ... return 123; }
```

What happens in a function call? The flow of the declaration is now the same as the flow of control: the things on the left -- initialization of formal parameters -- happens first, and the things on the right -- production of a return value -- happen last.

I could go on at some additional length pointing out how the C style gets it completely backwards, but it is late. Summing up: first, type on the right is superior in almost every possible way, and second, it is very, very old. New languages which use this convention are the ones that are being consistent with traditional practice.

Comment: This ought to be the best SO answer ever. I may not agree with the types on the right being surperior, but i definitively get your points here. Seriously, great answer - wish I could accept it twice :).

Basically I am nearly blind. So my field of vision with screen magnification is tiny. So when I read with types on the left, I know what to expect. I also can look things up by their type. But - this is more of a personal thing in the long run. :)

Comment: Since you suggested it, I would love for you to expand on inconsistencies this causes in C# syntax, or any additional reasons why the C style gets it backwards. Fascinating answer in any case.

Comment: @Asik: Well just start listing all the places types appear in the language.  C# has `int x;` but also `class D : B`.  And `double M(int x)` but  also`Func<int, double>`. And `int[]` but also `List<int>`. And `(int)x` but also `Cast<int>(x)`. Normally a type declaration always appears to the left of its usage, but in generic methods the declared thing can appear to the left  `T M<T>()` And so on. There is no consistently followed rule in C# for where a type appears.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a web search, it is not hard to find the developers of newer languages answering this question in their own words.  For example, the Go developers have a [FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#declarations_backwards) on this, as well as an [entire article](http://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax) on their language blog.  Many programmers are so used to C-like languages that any alternative seems weird, so this question tends to come up a lot...

However, you could argue that the C type declaration syntax itself is odd at best.  The pattern-like features for pointers and function types become awkward and unintuitive very quickly, and were never developed as part of, or into, any kind of more general pattern-matching facility.  For the sake of familiarity, they were adopted to a greater or lesser degree by many successive C-like languages, but the feature itself sticks out as more of a failed experiment that we have to live with for the sake of backwards compatibility.

One advantage of extricating yourself from C type syntax is that it makes it easier to use types in more places than just declarations.  If you can place types conveniently wherever they make sense, you can use your types as annotation, as described in the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID445).

Comment: I wouldn't say that the experiment has *failed*; the failed experiment is the one we learned nothing from. Hopefully we learned from the experiment that human-readable type annotations are important, and what design elements of a type annotation syntax benefit compiler writers and developers alike.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - and links! Will get to read them in a bit. Interesting standpoint, too. But I do agree with @Eric - it isn't exactly a failed experiment since for some oddballs - like me :p - it feels more nature that way now, and it has its own advantages, tiny in comparsion to the other way, of course. Anyway, great answer - thanks!